# Rails 3 App on ruby 1.9.2 mysteriously missing Base64 methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionpack

Trying to implement HTTP digest authentication in a Rails ApplicationController but am getting an enexpected exception on my call to `authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest(REALM)`:

```
undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass
```

Top of stacktrace:

```
/Users/chadmiko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/base64.rb:58:in
`decode64' actionpack (3.2.8)
lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:301:in
`validate_nonce' actionpack (3.2.8)
lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:188:in
`validate_digest_response' actionpack (3.2.8)
lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:179:in
`authenticate' actionpack (3.2.8)
lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:168:in
`authenticate_with_http_digest' actionpack (3.2.8)
lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:163:in
`authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest'
```

Other outputs (note: I'm using rvm and have created a project gemset):

```
chadmiko [ ~/Documents/Projects/msa-web ]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
chadmiko [ ~/Documents/Projects/msa-web ]$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.8
```

Also, if I startup irb:

```
chadmiko [ ~/Documents/Projects/msa-web ]$ irb
1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'base64'
 => true
```

Feel like there's a simple solution here but I'm just missing it.  Any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Solved.  Reinstalling RVM cleared up my issues.

Comment: plz help me wid my code too..similar to urs ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980880/sending-input-type-image-to-a-folder-on-the-server/21982678?noredirect=1#comment33314830_21982678